# How to achieve a ripple animation by clicking on a menu item?

Tags: android, android-menu

- I have a toolbar
- There is a overflow that displays options in menu
- On click of menu item, How to achieve a ripple animation

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menuEventsTodayId"
          android:title="@string/menu_events_today" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuUpcomingEventsId"
          android:title="@string/menu_upcoming_events" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuSignOutId"
          android:title="@string/menu_sign_out" />

</menu>
```

**I tried with:**

```
<item android:id="@+id/menuEventsTodayId"
          android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
          android:title="@string/menu_events_today" />
```

**Its not working, How to properly achieve it**

Comment: You can create custom ripple effect drawable file

Answer (score 0):

Just add the background as `?attr/selectableItemBackground`. It will automatically give ripple on Android 5+

Comment: Background to menu item or the toolbar ? ... I added to menu its not having any effect

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a separate style for your toolbar in the 'values' folder then add the following items to it:

```
<item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
```

Note:- As you can check this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations#Reveal). `?android:selectableItemBackground` is only properties which makes this animation.

Comment: I tried this Solution from here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118967/1083093)... its not working

Comment: which version are you checking ?

Comment: I am using Oreo ... I can see WhatsApp in my device having this effect ... but my app is not getting this effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use following for android version above lollipop:

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

for prelollipop devices, you can use following:

> compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

Comment: does this provide a ripple effect on menu click ... For buttons we can achieve it using above code ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117818/how-do-i-get-the-ripple-effect-for-menu-items-on-my-custom-toolbar

Comment: Yes ... Its not happening only for menu items ... I am able to achieve Ripple for all other widgets

Comment: You can do it by following

app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_background_ripple" in your navigationView

and create following ripple drawable and add it to drawablev21
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:radius="10dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" >

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <item
            android:id="@android:id/mask"
            android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</ripple>